# How to get attribute information of a custom field in registration form

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I have created a custom attribute for customer in Magento 2 site.

The HTML of the field is this:

```
        <input type="text"
               name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('custom')) ?>"
               id="custom" 
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getCustom()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('custom')) ?>"
               class="input-text" 
               data-validate="{required:true, 'validateData':true}">
```

Look at all `$block` calls. None of them works.

`$block->getFieldName('custom')` returns an empty string

`$block->getObject()->getCustom()` throws an exception because `getObject` is null

`$block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('custom')` throws an exception because `$block->getAttributeData()` is null.

How can I do it?

The field value is something that should be retrieved dynamically, because if there is an error in the registration form, and the page is reloaded, all fields should be repopulated. This works for all standard fields but not for the custom ones.

EDIT:

This is how I am creating the attribute:

```
public function addCustomAttribute()
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();


    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'custom',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom label',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => 1,
            'visible' => 1,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'sort_order' => 1,
            'position' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
        ]
    );

    $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
    $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom');
    $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
    $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
        'adminhtml_customer',
    ]);

    $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
}
```

Comment: How you created this fields?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya the standard way to do it, as shown in this page: https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-custom-field-to-registration-page-magento-2/. I think I need to create a model, but I have not found information about this. It seems nobody cares about re-populating the field when page is reloaded.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have updated the question just with the code that created the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no a simple way to do this, I have just hardcoded the input field attributes. It is better than complicating things creating a custom block class just for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the files into this forms as well.

```
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
        'adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit'
    ]);
```

Comment: This is how I have it now: `$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit',
            'checkout_index_index'
        ])`..... and to test, in the edit form, I had this: `name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('custom')) ?>"`. The result, `name` attribute is empty.